# How to run Xdebug on Laravel built-in server?

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code, xdebug

Xdebug is not running for Laravel project in VSCode.

I can not debug my code on `127.0.0.1:8000` which is a Laravel built-in server,
even `localhost:8000` can deal with Xdebug, I can only get Xdebug running on `localhost//laragon/whatever-laravel-project/public`.

I am wondering if there is a way to run Xdebug on `127.0.0.1:8000`.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: By "Laravel built-in server" you mean `php artisan serve`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use Xdebug with the built in PHP test server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27496543/is-it-possible-to-use-xdebug-with-the-built-in-php-test-server)